# What does Instance() do in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What does this line do in python?

```
user_magics = Instance('IPython.core.magics.UserMagics', allow_none=True)
```

note that `UserMagics` is an empty class defined in `IPython.core.magics.__init__.py` like this:

```
@magics_class
class UserMagics(Magics):
    """Placeholder for user-defined magics to be added at runtime.
```

What is the difference between the above and this definition?

```
user_magics = UserMagics()
```

Note as Blender points out below, this is part of the trailets package, and not base Python.

Comment: `Instance` isn't part of Python.

Comment: It's documented in the `traitlets` package: https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trait_types.html#classes-and-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instance` is part of the [`traitlets` package](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trait_types.html#classes-and-instances). From the documentation:

> In short, traitlets let the user define classes that have
>
> 1. Attributes (traits) with type checking and dynamically computed default values
> 2. Traits emit change events when attributes are modified
> 3. Traitlets perform some validation and allow coercion of new trait values on assignment. They also allow the user to define custom
>      validation logic for attributes based on the value of other
>      attributes.

Here's an example of what the package does, specifically using `Instance`:

```
from traitlets import HasTraits, Int, Instance

class Foo(object):
    pass

class MyObject(HasTraits):
    num = Int()
    foo = Instance(Foo, allow_none=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # works
    a = MyObject()
    a.num = 10
    a.foo = Foo()

    # works
    b = MyObject()
    b.num = 5
    b.foo = None

    # breaks
    c = MyObject()
    c.num = -1
    c.foo = object()  # The 'foo' trait of a MyObject instance must be a Foo or None, but a value of type 'object' was specified.
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks Blender!  Updated the tag for the question to include traitlets.